# Moto E device activity launch mode issue

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, motorola

In Moto E Device most of applications are crashing when I press back key.Those application are working in other device with same Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

Moto E device  activity launch mode default is single task.Change launcher mode to standard if you want make as default.